# C++ Access violation reading location 0xE3A26369

Tags: c++, access-violation

I am trying to create a simple 2D and output the array when i get this prompt saying Access violation reading location 0xE3A26369. I have no clue why this is happening because i have done this before and it never gave me this problem .

```
{
    string Board[6][6] = { "test", "test", "test", "test", "test",
                           "test", "test", "test", "test", "test",
                           "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", 
                           "test", "test", "test", "test", "test",
                           "test", "test", "test", "test", "test" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            cout << Board[i][j] << endl; //this line 

        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: You're reading more elements than your array contains.

Comment: The thing with accessing out of bounds is exactly what happens [is undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Sometimes you get the right answer. Sometimes you get a boot to the head. You can't count on any result, right or wrong or crash.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access indices of an array (indices 6 through 9 in both directions) that are out of bounds since `Board` is only 6x6. This gives you an access violation, because the memory is out of the scope of the program and the program is not allowed access to it.

To fix this, only iterate i and j over 0 through 5 (<6). Also, consider using [vectors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, as they have a built-in `size` function that you can use as the bounds (`v.size()` and `v[0].size` for each direction).

Also, you only populated `Board` with 5x5 values, not 6x6, which may give you behavior you don't want as well (though likely not the error you're seeing now).